# Comparing chars

Tags: c

for my word game i'm comparing chars in words, 6 in the first word, 6 in the random word.

Now I want it to do things when certain letters are on there place.

for example if

```
(aChar1 == aChar7 && aChar2 == aChar8){
//do something
}
```

but later in my code there is

```
(aChar1 == aChar7 && aChar2 == aChar8 && aChar3 == aChar9){
//do something
}
```

Now I just want the second code line to happen and not the first since that is only if the first 2 are in place. I need to add code like :

```
(aChar1 == aChar7 && aChar2 == aChar8 && aChar3 isnotequalto aChar9){
//do something
}
```

What code should I use for saying not equal?

Comment: `!=` -- chars are numbers and you use the same compare operators as for numbers.

Comment: (Note that this is basic C stuff, and you should learn C pretty well before you attempt Objective-C.  Most Objective-C references assume you have a good understanding of C before you start.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this and tell me if it works
    achar3!=achar9

Comment: thanks :D I'll try it out but there is a lot of code to edit so give me a min hah